# MysqliDb - check if the connection is closed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-mysqlidb

Im using this class https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class  (MysqliDb.php) which works fine however i cant determine if the connection to mysql closes automatically or if i need to close the connection somehow at the end of my file(s) that are using the class.

How to check if the connection is closed or has closed?

Comment: From PHP.net: Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically destroyed when a PHP script finishes its execution. So, while explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets is optional, doing so is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard php function [mysqli_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php): Pings a server connection, or tries to reconnect if the connection has gone down.

In the library this is `ping()`.

```
if (!$db->ping())
    $db->connect()
```

Look in the [documentation](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#helper-methods).

Answer (score 0):

The mysqli class has a method to this:

```
 bool mysqli::get_connection_stats ( void )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-connection-stats.php

To use with this class you need get the mysqli instance:

```
$db = new MysqliDb;
$instance = $db->mysqli();
$connStat = $instance->get_connection_stats();
var_dump($connStat);
```

This class that you are using close the connection automatically when destroyed through the magic method __destruct()

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.destruct